# GetFolder on server

Tags: vbscript, scripting, filesystemobject, movefile

I want to use `FileSystemObject` to get the name of a folder and rename a file with VBScript (`MoveFile`).
So:

```
Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")   
folder = "collab\met\met0025\myFolder"
Set f = oFSO.GetFolder(folder)
response.write f
```

Path folder is on a Sharepoint server (`http://collab/met/met0025/myFolder`).

But I have this error message:

> Erreur d'exécution Microsoft VBScript erreur '800a004c'
>   Chemin d'accès introuvable

Does someone know why?

Comment: `http:` prefix stands for Hyper Text Transfer Protocol, which isn't supportred by FSO. Could you please add the screenshot when you open `http://collab/met/met0025/myFolder`?

Comment: In fact, http://collab is a Sharepoint library. And after some tests, I've seen that it seems to not be possible to acces a file in that case.

I know UNC path are important. So I test with :
\\collab\met\met0025\myFolder. 
Dosen't work.

Comment: @Patix80 Can you map the URI to a drive letter? Something like `CreateObject("WScript.Network").MapNetworkDrive("X:", "http://collab/met/met0025/myFolder")`.

Comment: does not work. I think Sharpoint library have some restricted acces. So, i will find a other way to solve my problem. thanks!